# Can we choose max and min speeds for each traffic lane in Flow project?

Tags: python, sumo, flow-project

It seems that we can only set the whole limmitted speed for all the lanes in created road, and we can't set the limitted speed for single lanes in the situation of lane changing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no such thing as a min speed. As for the max speed, I don't think Flow supports it for lanes, but you can call sumo's `setMaxSpeed(laneID, speed)` function to set it manually ([doc](https://sumo.dlr.de/pydoc/traci.html) > _lane).

Comment: Hello! I try " traci.lane.setMaxSpeed("highway_0_3", 33.333)" in the last line of highway.py of latest flow version. But it shows:
File "/home/hongyong/.conda/envs/flow_new2/lib/python3.7/site-packages/traci/_lane.py", line 315, in setMaxSpeed
    self._connection._sendDoubleCmd(
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute '_sendDoubleCmd'

Comment: I check python3.7/site-packages/traci/_lane.py and find that _connection is not linked correctly to connection.py. How should I use setMaxSpeed in flow python file? Thanks!

Comment: I add "import traci" in the beginning, and other part is the same with highway.py in example.